# Cleanup this program

Tags: python, try-catch

I finally got it working!  But for some reason the program prints out the previous error statement (too high or too low or please enter values between...), along with the value error message if the user enters in something that the try catches.  Could anyone explain why?  Any shortening/cleanup is also welcome.  Sorry for any errors.  Thanks!

```
'''
This is a guessing game that finds a random number, and then
Tells the user if their guess is too low or too high.  It will also give
Error messages for any numbers outside of the accepted range, and will also
Give errors for anything not an integer.
At the end (if the user guesses correctly) it will ask if the
User would like to play again or quit.
'''

import random


def start_here():
    print("Welcome to the guessing game!")
    play_game()


def play_game():

    random_number = random.randrange(1, 100)
    correct = False
    user_guess = True

    while not correct:

        try:
            user_guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please only use integers")

        if user_guess > 100 or user_guess < 1:
            print("Please only enter numbers between 1 and 100!")

        elif user_guess > random_number:
            print("Too high, try again. ")

        elif user_guess < random_number:
            print("Too low, try again! ")

        elif user_guess == random_number:
            break

    if user_guess == random_number:
        replay = (input("Great!  You guessed it! would you like to play again? y or n"))
        if replay == "y":
            start_here()
        else:
            print("See ya later!")


start_here()
```

Comment: You caught me before the edit!  Pasted

Comment: Note how if an exception is thrown, you never assign `user_guess` to anything, but then still check what message needs to be printed. I'd write an answer, but code copying is quite broken on mobile.

Comment: @NaruS: comparing an int to a `list` (Python2) or `range` object (Python3) will always return False. And testing for containment (ie `user_guess in range(1, 100)` is a pure waste of cpu cycles (it has to scan the iterable - whether range or list - to find if it contains the value). The current test (`user_guess > 100 or user_guess < 1`) is simple, explicit and efficient, no need to change it for something that doesn't improve readability and  is either broken (equality test) or at best much less efficient (containment test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the code after the try-except block gets executed irrespective of whether an exception was thrown or not. If the except block gets invoked you want your code to skip through the rest of the statements in the while loop and `continue` at the next iteration of the loop, where the user is prompted for input again. This can be achieved by using the `continue` keyword in the `except` block like so:

```
try:
     user_guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))
except ValueError:
     print("Please only use integers")
     continue
```

The `continue` statement directs the interpreter to skip the remaining statements in the current iteration of the loop. The flow of control can then re-enter the loop or exit, depending on the loop condition.

Now that your code runs the way it is intended to, here is how you can make it more concise:

Firstly, there is a neat feature in Python which allows you to write conditions like `not 1 <= user_guess <= 100`.  These conditions are much quicker to read, and you can replace this in your code.

Secondly, the `start_here()` function is redundant. You can easily replace `play_game()` in its place with a few modifications like so:

```
import random

def play_game():
    print("Welcome to the guessing game!")  #Modification here
    random_number = random.randrange(1, 100)
    correct = False
    user_guess = True

    while not correct:

        try:
            user_guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please only use integers")
            continue #Modification here

        if not 1<=user_guess<=100: #Modification here
            print("Please only enter numbers between 1 and 100!")

        elif user_guess > random_number:
            print("Too high, try again. ")

        elif user_guess < random_number:
            print("Too low, try again! ")

        elif user_guess == random_number:
            break

    if user_guess == random_number:
        replay = (input("Great!  You guessed it! would you like to play again? y or n"))
        if replay == "y":
            play_game()  #Modification here
        else:
            print("See ya later!")


play_game()  #Modification here
```

or you could entirely replace the `play_game()` function with a while loop like so:

```
import random

replay = 'y'  #Modification here

while replay == 'y': #Modification here
    print("Welcome to the guessing game!")
    random_number = random.randrange(1, 100)
    correct = False
    user_guess = True

    while not correct:

        try:
            user_guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please only use integers")
            continue

        if not 1<=user_guess<=100 :
            print("Please only enter numbers between 1 and 100!")

        elif user_guess > random_number:
            print("Too high, try again. ")

        elif user_guess < random_number:
            print("Too low, try again! ")

        elif user_guess == random_number:
            break

    if user_guess == random_number: #Modification here
        replay = input("Great!  You guessed it! would you like to play again? y or n")


print("See ya later!") #Modification here
```

Comment: Yep forgot continue.  Thanks very much for the update also makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
while not correct:

    try:
        user_guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please only use integers")

    if user_guess > 100 or user_guess < 1:
       # etc
```

If the user input is not a valid int, you display an error message but still proceed with testing the value against the random number. You should instead skip the rest of the loop, or extract the part getting the user input into it's own loop. As a general rule, one function should do only one thing, then you use another function to control the whole program's flow:

```
def get_num():
    while True:
        try:
            user_guess = int(input("Enter your guess: ").strip())
        except ValueError:
            print("Please only use integers")
            continue

        if user_guess > 100 or user_guess < 1:
            print("Please only enter numbers between 1 and 100!")
            continue

        return user_guess

def again():
    replay = input("would you like to play again? y or n"))
    return replay.strip().lower() == "y"

def play_game():
    random_number = random.randrange(1, 100)
    while True:
        user_guess = get_num()
        if user_guess > random_number:
            print("Too high, try again. ")
        elif user_guess < random_number:
            print("Too low, try again! ")
        else:
            # if it's neither too high nor too low then it's equal...
            break

    # no need to test again, we can only get here when the user
    # found the number
    print("Great!  You guessed it!")

def main():
    print("Welcome to the guessing game!")
    while True:
        play_game()
        if not again():
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```